# Set the css class of a div using code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I understand that we can set the various style attributes from code behind using :

```
divControl.Style("height") = "200px"
```

But how to set it's class instead of declaring each of the styles from code?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**C#**

```
divControl.Attributes["class"] = "myClass";
```

**VB**

```
divControl.Attributes("class") = "myClass"
```

You'll need to have a rule like this one on your css file

```
.myClass
{
   height:200px; 
   /*...more styles*/
}
```

Comment: Write that in VB.NET instead of C# and it'll be perfect.

Comment: @Andrew Morton: he states on the question that VB or C# is fine but thanks for the suggestion, added VB code.

Answer (score 3):

This way you can define full style inline, without separate class declaration:

```
divControl.Attributes("style") = "height:200px; color:Red"
```

Comment: OP wants to set the `class` attribute of the div, not set styles individually.

Comment: Although the question specifically says that this is not the answer he is looking for, I gave it an up-vote because it helped me (google took me here when asking about the dynamic styles).

Comment: I found Yuriy's suggestion helpful for those situations where you need a one-time quick style fix dynamically.